# ASP.NET WebAPI doesn't insert records into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing difficulties in inserting records in a database. I don't know in fact what's going wrong.

**What I want to do**: I want to insert a new Club entity with a POST request to the Web API.

**What happens**: Nothing gets inserted, even though I call Save() method of UnitOfWork object which calls SaveChanges() on the context.

The code for the request is the following:

```
    public async Task<bool> Create(Club club)
    {
        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(club));
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

        var response = await Client.PostAsync("api/clubs/Add", httpContent); // client is of type HttpClient

        try
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ... error handling here ...
        }

        return true;
    }
```

The code which inserts the record from the API:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Add(Club club)
    {
        UnitOfWork.ClubsRepository.Add(club);
        UnitOfWork.Save();

        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Club>(HttpStatusCode.Created, club);
        return response;
    }
```

UnitOfWork class:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private FootballTransfersContext context = new FootballTransfersContext();
    private IClubsRepository clubsRepository;
    private IPlayersRepository playersRepository;
    private ITransfersRepository transfersRepository;
    private ICountriesRepository countriesRepository;
    private IPositionsRepository positionsRepository;

    private bool disposed;

    public IClubsRepository ClubsRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.clubsRepository == null)
                this.clubsRepository = new ClubsRepository(context);
            return this.clubsRepository;
        }
    }

    public IPlayersRepository PlayersRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.playersRepository == null)
                this.playersRepository = new PlayersRepository(context);
            return this.playersRepository;
        }
    }

    public ITransfersRepository TransfersRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.transfersRepository == null)
                this.transfersRepository = new TransfersRepository(context);
            return this.transfersRepository;
        }
    }

    public ICountriesRepository CountriesRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.countriesRepository == null)
                this.countriesRepository = new CountriesRepository(context);
            return this.countriesRepository;
        }
    }

    public IPositionsRepository PositionsRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.positionsRepository == null)
                this.positionsRepository = new PositionsRepository(context);
            return this.positionsRepository;
        }
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

The UnitOfWork object holds all the repositories and uses a single DB context as you might suggest. The interesting part is that **it returns success code even if I try to insert null instead of club variable**.

Clubs repository code:

```
 public class ClubsRepository : IClubsRepository
{
    private FootballTransfersContext db;

    public ClubsRepository()
    {
        this.db = new FootballTransfersContext();
    }

    public ClubsRepository(FootballTransfersContext context)
    {
        this.db = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<Club> GetAll()
    {
        return db.Clubs;
    }

    public Club GetById(int id)
    {
        Club club = db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClubID == id);
        return club;
    }

    public void Add(Club club)
    {
        db.Clubs.Add(club);
    }

    public void Update(Club club)
    {
        db.Entry(club).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        Club club = GetById(id);
        db.Clubs.Remove(club);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Club> GetClubsBySearchTerm(string search)
    {
        var results = db.Clubs.Where(x => x.ClubName.IndexOf(search) != -1);
        return results;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Club> GetClubsBySearchTermMatchBeginning(string search)
    {
        var results = db.Clubs.Where(x => x.ClubName.StartsWith(search));
        return results;
    }

    public Club GetClubByName(string name)
    {
        Club clubFound = db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClubName == name);
        return clubFound;
    }

    public bool IsUniqueClub(string oldName, string oldManager, Club club, ref bool uniqueClubName, ref bool uniqueManager)
    {
        if (club.ClubName != oldName)
        {
            if (db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClubName == club.ClubName) != null)
            {
                uniqueClubName = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (club.Manager != oldManager)
        {
            if (db.Clubs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Manager == club.Manager) != null)
            {
                uniqueManager = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the action from the controller of the client application:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Club club)
    {       
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Club clubFound = await (clubsRequestClient as ClubsRequestClient).RequestClubByName(club.ClubName); //UnitOfWork.ClubsRepository.GetClubByName(club.ClubName);

            if (clubFound != null)
            {
                ViewBag.CountryID = new SelectList(await countriesRequestClient.GetAll(), "CountryID", "CountryName");
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The club already exists in the database!");
                return View(club);
            }
            else
            {
                bool isSuccess = await (clubsRequestClient as ClubsRequestClient).Create(club);
                //UnitOfWork.ClubsRepository.Add(club);
                if (isSuccess)
                {
                    //UnitOfWork.Save();
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Club successfully added.";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
        }

        return View();           
    }
```

Comment: Show the code of your UnitOfWork class.

Comment: You might havn't changed the target context at all (didnt actually inset a row)

Comment: I added the code for the UoW class.

Comment: Is `Club` a viewmodel or an actual entity? Seems to me the issue lies in the repository, worth posting the implementation of the `ClubRepository`.

Comment: I added that as well. It's a database entity, not a viewmodel. Altihogh there's another parameterless constructor, I must mention I always use the other one, which accepts the context from the UoW.

Comment: Also please show how you initialize your database context. Not that you have the DropCreateDatabaseAlways initializer. ;-)

Comment: Also, instead of `FirstOrDefault(..) != null` you can also just use `.Any()`. When the collection is not loaded, this will be a LOT faster, because you don't retrieve the whole entity.

Comment: It seems that the repository and the context don't have anything to do with each other. When you call Save() on the context, how does this update the DB in the repository (which I assume is a Entity Framework DB context)?

Comment: Slavo, the context is shared between all the repositories, so when I'm done with all the work I just save the changes once, instead of everytime i do something to the database. This worked 100% correctly when I didn't use web service (when I used the repositories directly in the actions of the controllers of the client MVC application). 
@user2674389, you're right about Any(), thanks. Also what do you mean by "how I initialize the context", it's the default class generated by EF.

Comment: I added the action of the client MVC app which initiates the request. I was wondering could it be something about those async operations, I'm kinda to new to them, haven't used them before.

Comment: OK, so I discovered the response code is 500 Internal Server Error instead of Success as I was thinking. Sorry to confuse you all. I guess it's something aboout the Club object being null or something, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was with the serialization. I made DTO objects of the entities and everything went fine.